# Unit vector of an angle in plane polar coordinates

Tags: vectors, polar-coordinates

I'm struggling to find any information, about how the tip of a unit vector of an angle in plane polar coordinates, $\hat u_{\theta}$, describes a circle - if $P$ is a moving particle - with an angle of $\pi/2+\theta$ instead of just $\theta$.

Help would be much appreciated.

Edit:
I've attached a diagram from my notes to help further explain my question.

[image: Diagram of unit vector components]

Comment: What is meant by $\hat u$?

Comment: It's just the notation that is used in my course to describe a unit vector of a moving particle in polar coordinates.

Comment: Which vector are you suggesting describes a circle?

Comment: The vector r describes a circle if P is a moving particle. Where ûθ & ûr are the basis for the vector, representing the angle and radius respectively.